# Adjusting Navigation Bar Size on Wordpress Template WP Clarion

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I cant for the life of me increase the size on the navbar below, I've contacted the developers through support but need to get it done tonight :/

penarthpc.com/~nuvolaor/

There are no variables in the theme anywhere unfortunately.

I am going to keep playing with Firebug but appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

The div .rt-container has a fixed width of 960px and encompasses most of the website. If you adjusted the width of this container and then add another css style width:'' to #rt-navigation you can increase the width of the Navigation Bar.

---

If you need to increase the height of .rt-navigation then add a css height:'' property to *#rt-navigation .rt-container {}* contained in main-light.css, Line 122.

After this you will need to adjust the height of the logo. Change the value of the height on #logo-inner.

The navigation buttons are still fixed to their original height. Change / Create a new height value for .rt-menubar, .menutop li, .rt-menubar li etc etc.

Comment: I should have mentioned I want to adjust the height of the navbar!

Comment: Just made a few amendments to my original answer.

Comment: I cant get the navbar items to resize

Comment: Change the height of the following css. ".menutop li.root > .item {line-height:75px}" and the height of .menutop

Comment: If you look through the code you will find that the navigation buttons use a fixed background image called 'navigation-bg.png' which is why when you increase the height it still looks like the buttons are the same height - the background does not stretch.